# Unable to create EC2 instance using Ansible

Tags: linux, centos, rhel, ansible

```
- name: Create VPC
  ec2_vpc_net:
    name: arunvpc
    cidr_block: 10.4.0.0/16
    region: ap-northeast-1
    aws_access_key: "{{ aws_access_key }}"
    aws_secret_key: "{{ aws_secret_key }}"
    state: "present"
 register: my_vpc


- name: saving vpc id
  set_fact:
    vpc_id: "{{ my_vpc.vpc.id }}"


- name: creating subnet
  ec2_vpc_subnet:
     state: present
     vpc_id: "{{ vpc_id }}"
     cidr: 10.4.0.0/24
     region: ap-northeast-1
     aws_access_key: "{{ aws_access_key }}"
     aws_secret_key: "{{ aws_secret_key }}"
     resource_tags:
         name: "arun_subnet"
 register: my_subnet


- name: saving subnet id
  set_fact:
     sub_id: "{{ my_subnet.subnet.id }}"


- name: creating security group
  ec2_group:
      name: my_security_group
      description: security
      vpc_id: "{{ vpc_id }}"
      region: ap-northeast-1
      aws_access_key: "{{ aws_access_key }}"
      aws_secret_key: "{{ aws_secret_key }}"
      rules:
        - proto: tcp
          from_port: 22
          to_port: 22
          cidr_ip: 0.0.0.0/0


- name: creating linux vm
  ec2:
    key_name: my_key
    group: my_security_group
    instance_type: m1.small
    image: ami-775e4f16
    instance_tags:
      Name: arunlinux
    wait: yes
    region: ap-northeast-1
    count: 1
    vpc_subnet_id: "{{ sub_id }}"
    assign_public_ip: yes
  register: ec2_out
```

While executing this playbook, I am getting following error:

```
TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [vpc : Create VPC] ********************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [vpc : saving vpc id] *****************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [vpc : creating subnet] ***************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [vpc : saving subnet id] **************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [vpc : creating security group] *******************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [vpc : creating linux vm] *************************************************
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ProfileNotFoundError'
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_9UtXSg/ansible_module_ec2.py\", line 1725, in <module>\n    main()\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_9UtXSg/ansible_module_ec2.py\", line 1673, in main\n    ec2 = ec2_connect(module)\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_9UtXSg/ansible_modlib.zip/ansible/module_utils/ec2.py\", line 320, in ec2_connect\nAttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ProfileNotFoundError'\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", "rc": 0}
to retry, use: --limit @/playbooks/aws/main.retry

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=6    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

Note: the key-pair is already present. Client is CentOS 7 machine.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't set `aws_access_key` and `aws_secret_key` in task "creating linux vm".

As I think, it is bad idea to store credentials in Ansible (except Ansible Vault). It is better to keep them in separate shell-file and use before run playbook, for example:

File with credentials, `aws_testing_profile.sh`:

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=''
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=''
```

run playbook:

```
source aws_testing_profile.sh
ansible-playbook -i inventory/testing/ my_playbook.yml
```

Of course, you can keep credentials in `~/.aws/credentials`, but I don't like it, because any command you run will have your AWS rights without confirmation.